# querySelector or getElementById not working

Tags: javascript, html, json, variables

So i am in the process of making a web app (experimental) that has a quiz in it. I am using a python file for questions and the function for the quiz.
The problem is with the javascript, it is not selecting the tags that i want.
Here's the code

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Quiz Begin
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

{% for q in qna %}
<div>
    <h3>{{ q["question"] }} </h3>
    <input class="{{ q['id'] }}" type="text">
    <p class="{{ q['id'] }}" style="display:none;">{{ q["answer"] }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}

<footer>
    <button id="check">Check Answer</button>
</footer>

<script>

    // correct this or start from scratch because this is not working

    var qna = {{ qna | tojson }};
    var right = 0;
    var wrong = 0;

    document.querySelector("#check").addEventListener('click', function() {
        var id, tmp, input, answer;
        for (let q = parseInt("{{ qna[0]['id'] }}"); q <= parseInt("{{ qna|length }}"); q++) {
            id = q.toString();
            tmp = document.getElementsByClassName(id);
            input = tmp.querySelector('input').value.toUpperCase();
            answer = tmp.getElementByTagName('p').value.toUpperCase();
            if (parseInt(input) == parseInt(answer)) {
                right++;
            }
            else {
                wrong++;
            }
        }
    });
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

The python codes are

```
def quiz_begin():
return render_template("begin.html", qna=questions())
```

And

```
def questions():
return [{"id": 1,
        "question": "2 + 2 = ?",
        "answer": 4},
        {"id": 2,
        "question": "68 x 45 = ?",
        "answer": 3060},]
```

The problem lies after the tmp variable is declared in the script.
the tmp.querySelector doesn't seem to work and return the tag. It just stops there. I have tried some different functions like getElementByTagName but they dont seem to work either. if there is any other way then please help.
Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: First of all, if this is a class name, why name the variable "id"? Secondly, have you tried:             tmp = document.querySelector("." + id);

Comment: Note: it's `getElementsByTagName` (plural) which returns a live HMTL collection (similar to `getElementsByClassName`), and you can't grab a value from a collection. You'll either need to loop over it, or get the element you want from it with an index.

Comment: @Andy I used index after you pointed it out and now it works. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: `tmp.querySelector('p')` might be easier @DinoNyte if you're looking to get the first element.

Comment: @Andy I need the p element of the next question on each jinja loop iteration. so the indices work better

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection` (iterator of node elements), so you should loop througt them, oder take a single one, like:

```js
tmps = document.getElementsByClassName(id);
for(let j = 0; j < tmps.length, j++) {
    input = tmps[j].querySelector('input').value.toUpperCase();
}
```

or

```js
tmps = document.getElementsByClassName(id);
if (tmps.length)
    input = tmps[0].querySelector('input').value.toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector` uses the CSS selector syntax to find elements. Did you try this?

```js
tmp = document.querySelector('.' + id);
```

For querying by class names e.g. "foo" you can use `document.querySelector('.foo')`.

But be aware that `document.querySelector` will return you only the first element found in the DOM. Whereas `document.querySelectorAll` would return you also an HTMLCollection.